# Find the number of arrangements where no two vowels come together in a given word.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

All the letters of the word "eamcot" are arranged in different possible ways.
Find the number of arrangements where no two vowels come together.

The approach I used -
Assume you have 6 slots.
You can fill the first slot in two broader ways - vowel or consonant.
According to this choice all the next places have already been decided because you can only go in an alternating manner due to the condition.
Now for filling all the consonants you can do that in 3! ways and vowels in 3! ways as well.
So the final answer is 3!*3!*2 = 72.
(The two is accounting for the 2nd step)

But all over the internet I am getting the answer as 144.
They do the following -
You know that any such permutation can be written as cvcvcvc (one of the "c"s is empty).
Now filling all "v"s is 3! and filling all "c"s is 4! (I think the problem here is that you can only have the empty space either on the start or end only and not anywhere else and hence 4! is incorrect) and they get the answer as 144.

Which of the two approaches is correct?

Comment: I also make the answer to be 72, the second method is wrong for exactly the reason you give.

Comment: The problem does not say that no two consonants can be adjacent.

Comment: Apologies for the error:  the official solution is indeed correct numerically, though the phrasing is odd.  A combination like $EMCOTA$ is fine.  Thus you should write the *consonants* out as $\_c_1\_c_2\_c_3\_$  ($3!$ ways to do that) and now arrange the three vowels and a blank however you like.  The other method is correct if you add the assumption that no consonants can be consecutive, but of course that was not part of the problem statement.

Comment: @jpmacmanus  The answer is indeed $144$, although the method used to find that answer is wrong.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I somehow didn't spot that we could indeed have two consonants together, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem states that no two vowels are adjacent.  It does not say that no two consonants are adjacent. Therefore, your answer is wrong, as is the justification for the correct answer that you found on the internet.

Arrange the three distinct consonants in $3!$ ways.  That creates four spaces in which we can place the three vowels, two between successive consonants and two at the ends of the row.
$$\square C_1 \square C_2 \square C_3 \square$$
In the diagram, $C_i$ represents the position of the $i$th consonant and the squares represent the spaces where a vowel can be placed.  To separate the vowels, we must choose three of these four spaces in which to place a vowel, which can be done in $\binom{4}{3}$ ways.  The three distinct vowels can be arranged in the selected spaces in $3!$ ways.  Hence, the number of arrangements of the letters of the word EAMCOT in which no two vowels are adjacent is
$$3!\binom{4}{3}3! = 144$$

Comment: Ohh I understand. So basically we can have an empty space in the center as long as vowels are seperate.

Answer (score 1):

Another correct way to get the correct answer is to  consider the consonants as blue balls, the vowels as red balls, and place the consonants one by one followed by placing vowels one by one.

Each consonant placed creates an extra placement possibility for the next ball, but each vowel placed "eats up" one place for the next one due to the non-adjacentcy clause, thus

$(1*2*3)*(4*3*2) =144$